# Native app crash for Xamarin app in pre launch report

Tags: android, xamarin

I have a xamarin forms app, after the recent update the app crashes in pre launch report on Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge devices.

Here is the log extract:

```
12-25 05:13:24.069: D/EnterprisePartitionManager(3377): event : 281 7 remove_enc_dir failed
12-25 05:13:24.069: W/System.err(3377): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/system/users/sdp_engine_list.xml: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
12-25 05:13:24.069: W/System.err(3377):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
12-25 05:13:24.069: W/System.err(3377):     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76)
12-25 05:13:24.069: W/System.err(3377):     at com.android.server.SdpManagerService$SdpEngineDatabase$EngineListHandler.getEngineListLocked(SdpManagerService.java:1812)
12-25 05:13:24.069: W/System.err(3377):     at com.android.server.SdpManagerService$SdpEngineDatabase$EngineListHandler.access$900(SdpManagerService.java:1732)
12-25 05:13:24.069: W/System.err(3377):     at com.android.server.SdpManagerService$SdpEngineDatabase.getEngineListLocked(SdpManagerService.java:1716)
12-25 05:13:24.069: W/System.err(3377):     at com.android.server.SdpManagerService$SdpEngineDatabase.access$2100(SdpManagerService.java:1691)
12-25 05:13:24.069: W/System.err(3377):     at com.android.server.SdpManagerService.handlePkgRemoved(SdpManagerService.java:3039)
12-25 05:13:24.069: W/System.err(3377):     at com.android.server.SdpManagerService.access$2400(SdpManagerService.java:145)
12-25 05:13:24.069: W/System.err(3377):     at com.android.server.SdpManagerService$ActionReceiver.onReceive(SdpManagerService.java:3114)
12-25 05:13:24.069: W/System.err(3377):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:993)
12-25 05:13:24.069: W/System.err(3377):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
12-25 05:13:24.069: W/System.err(3377):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-25 05:13:24.069: W/System.err(3377):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
12-25 05:13:24.069: W/System.err(3377):     at com.android.server.SystemServer.run(SystemServer.java:508)
12-25 05:13:24.069: W/System.err(3377):     at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:363)
12-25 05:13:24.069: W/System.err(3377):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-25 05:13:24.069: W/System.err(3377):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
12-25 05:13:24.069: W/System.err(3377):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

I have no idea I what is needed to fix this kind of error.

Edit:
I'm getting this for every alternate pre-launch report while the other succeeds without code changes. I have now two thoughts a) this could be a build issue with Visual studio or b) some issue with pre launch report process itself

Comment: seems this file does not exist  /data/system/users/sdp_engine_list.xml

Comment: Since i'm using xamarin forms, this issue should not occur as i'm not reading any such files

Comment: have you tried with another device?

Comment: The app works on most devices. I say most as it did crash on a friends device at launch at times. The app even works on 9 other devices in Google's pre-launch report. Just doesn't work on S7, which seems odd to me.

Comment: because that seems a Samsung's file... you can try to add READ and WRITE file permission to your android manifest... only for a test....

Comment: I have a Read permission already set. I don't write any data so that is currently off.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know... on Google there aren't info about this problem...

Comment: @AlessandroCaliaro Thanks for your help so far..